# StopIteration with requests_ntlm

Tags: python

I am sending requests to an API that uses Windows authentication, or at least this is what I have been told. I therefore use `requests_ntlm` to authenticate, i.e.:

```
r = requests.get('https://my-api-url.com',
                  auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password))
```

this raises a StopIteration error somewhere inside the `requests_ntlm` library, this is the stack trace:

```
File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests_ntlm/requests_ntlm.py:168, in HttpNtlmAuth.response_hook(self, r, **kwargs)
    165     auth_type = _auth_type_from_header(www_authenticate)
    167     if auth_type is not None:
--> 168         return self.retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(
    169             "www-authenticate",
    170             "Authorization",
    171             r,
    172             auth_type,
    173             kwargs,
    174         )
    175 elif r.status_code == 407:
    176     # If we didn't have server auth, do proxy auth.
    177     proxy_authenticate = r.headers.get("proxy-authenticate", "").lower()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests_ntlm/requests_ntlm.py:137, in HttpNtlmAuth.retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(self, auth_header_field, auth_header, response, auth_type, args)
    133 auth_header_value = response2.headers[auth_header_field]
    135 auth_strip = auth_type + " "
--> 137 ntlm_header_value = next(
    138     s
    139     for s in (val.lstrip() for val in auth_header_value.split(","))
    140     if s.startswith(auth_strip)
    141 ).strip()
    143 # Parse the challenge in the ntlm context and perform
    144 # the second step of authentication
    145 val = base64.b64decode(ntlm_header_value[len(auth_strip) :].encode())

StopIteration:
```

I don't know very much about authentication so my understanding is a bit limited. From the stack trace and the [documentation for requests_ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm/blob/master/requests_ntlm/requests_ntlm.py) it seems to me that the request receives a 401 unauthorized response and the library therefore tries to get the response authentication header values is they start with "Negotiate" (I can see this when debugging my code), but this raises a StopIteration error because there are none.

My question now is, where is the problem here? Is it in the API or in my request? If the latter, what do I need to do to fix it? I use another API with Windows authentication and `requests_ntlm` and it works with no problems.